# Prevent UITableView default behavior during edit mode

Tags: iphone, ios, object

I have a `UITableView` controller that allows editing through a button, with `allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing` being set to **YES**.

During non-editing mode, selecting a cell will bring up a different view with cell specific data. What would be the best way to disable this during edit mode, as well as bring up an action sheet at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code

```
for (UIView* subview in [self subviews])
{
  if (![NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"])
  {
     // create/Initialize your detailView's object

  }
  else
  {
    //create your action sheet;
  }
}
```

This code write in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method

Comment: is subviews a getter for a property of self? I'm getting an error "no visible interface for ...". (sorry if noob question)

Comment: I configured it to this: UIView* subview in self.tableView.subviews, which works, but even without edit mode, the isEqualToString is returning true.

Comment: I logged all the subviews in the for loop, and the edit mode subview doesn't seem to be trigged when I press edit.

Answer (score 1):

I found out tableView has a handy "isEditing" property:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(self.tableView.isEditing) {
        //instantiate action sheet
    } else {
        //instantiate view
    }
}
```